# Which Byte is a Bit in?

Tags: byte, bit

A bit of a strange one but here goes....

How can I mathematically determine which byte a certain bit is in?

For example, if I have a 32-bit word there are four 8-bit bytes.  I would like to know which of these four bytes a certain bit is in.  So using some random bits as an example, bit 7 is in the first byte, bit 12 is in the second, 19 is in the third and so on.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you number your bits and bytes from zero, dividing by eight using integer division should do the trick:

```
 7 / 8 = 0 // Bit #7 is in byte #0
19 / 8 = 2 // Bit #19 is in byte #2
```